# How was the Boesmansgat Cave in South Africa formed?

Tags: geology, hydrogeology, underground-water

I found nearly nothing about [this sinkhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boesmansgat) online. Apparently the cave has water dating back thousands of years.

From where did this water come from.  Is it just rain? And how dirty is the water now?

Comment: Any geologists out here ?

Comment: Until I read your question I didn't know Boesmansgat Cave existed.

Comment: I can recommend to watch the documentary ‘Dave not coming back’, aside from the tragedy, it shows some context around the cave/sinkhole. The problem is that it doesn’t at all explain anything about where the cave came from.